# Passing checkbox value as a parameter to Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a following code in my WPF app.My xaml screen has 2 controls...checkbox button and a textbox.

I need to be able to trigger MandatoryFieldConverter and pass the checkbox value to it so that I can take an appropriate action.
How do I achieve this please?

Update:I tried using multivValue converter but its not working:

I tried following but my converter code is not getting triggered.Please advise.Thanks.

```
<CheckBox Name="chkPlaceholder" Command="{Binding PlaceholderCheckboxCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked}" Style="{DynamicResource PlaceholderToggleButtonStyle}" ></CheckBox>

    <TextBox Name="txtUnitFactor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding CommonSecurityAttributes.UnitFactor,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4" >
                <TextBox.Background>

                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomMandatoryFieldConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding ElementName="chkPlaceholder" Path= "IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked" />
                            <Binding ElementName="txtUnitFactor" Path= "CommonSecurityAttributes.UnitFactor" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Background>
                </TextBox>
```

MainWindowResources.cs:

```
<Converter:CustomMandatoryFieldBackgroundColourConverter x:Key="CustomMandatoryFieldConverter"/>
```

Thanks.

MainWindowXaml.cs

```
<CheckBox 
    Name="chkPlaceholder" 
    Command="{Binding PlaceholderCheckboxCommand}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    IsChecked="{Binding IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked}" 
    Style="{DynamicResource PlaceholderToggleButtonStyle}" 
    ></CheckBox>

<TextBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="180" 
    TabIndex="1" 
    Text="{Binding Price,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Background="{Binding CommonSecurityAttributes.UnitFactor,Converter ={StaticResource MandatoryFieldConverter}}" 
    Grid.Row="7" 
    Grid.Column="4"  />
```

C# Converter :

```
public class MandatoryFieldBackgroundColourConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string defaultBgColor = "BurlyWood";

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                {
                    return defaultBgColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "LightGreen";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return defaultBgColor;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }



public class CustomMandatoryFieldBackgroundColourConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string defaultBgColor = "BurlyWood";
        string validationSuccessColor = "LightGreen";
        bool isPlaceHolderChecked = false;

 if (value == null || value != null && value.Length == 0)
            return defaultBgColor;

        try
        {
            bool result = bool.TryParse(value[1].ToString(), out isPlaceHolderChecked);

            if (isPlaceHolderChecked)
            {
                return validationSuccessColor;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                return defaultBgColor;
            }
            else
            {
                return validationSuccessColor;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return defaultBgColor;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to pass *two* values to the converter, `CommonSecurityAttributes.UnitFactor` and `IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked`? If that's so, you want a multiconverter (IMultiValueConverter), not a regular valueconverter.

Comment: Yes, thats correct Ed.I tried following but my converter code is not getting triggered.Please advise.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.Please see my question updated.

Comment: What is CustomMandatoryFieldConverter? Can you show me the code for it? When you say it "doesn't work", can you tell me exactly what that means?

Comment: Sure,have added that code now.I checked in debug mode and its not getting triggered after putting a break point in Convert method.

Comment: Checkbox doesn't have a `IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked` property. Instead you have bound `IsChecked` to `IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked` in the checkbox. You need to either bind `IsChecked` or better, bind the same `IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked` from your View Model. Check the console when you are debugging. You probably have binding errors in there.

Comment: Heed Matt -- get rid of *both* ElementNames in your `<Binding ...` tags in that multiconverter. Both are properties of your viewmodel, not of those controls. Also you have a bug in your Convert in the multiconverter: You're converting value.ToString() when you want value[0].ToString()

Comment: Thanks Ed and Matt.Yes, now the converter code is getting invoked and I can now see checkbox value getting passed as a parameter in the converter.But still I dont see background property of textbox getting set after the convert code has invoked.(BTW,I had already added a check for null conditions in the converter..have updated my class now.)

Comment: You color is not changing because you are not returning a color from your convertor, you are returning a string. Return an actual color and it should work. WPF won't let you return a string and then automagically invoke another converter for you.

Comment: @MattBurland I think he needs not a color, but a Brush. `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BurlyWood);` etc.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Yes, you are right. I think it's a brush.

Comment: Awesome...thanks a ton both Matt and Ed.All working now!!

Comment: Matt, On an another note, returning a string does work for me using a converter class in the following case: ---->  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Width="180" Text="{Binding CommonSecurityAttributes.UltimateParentId}" TabIndex="4"  Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Background="{Binding CommonSecurityAttributes.MyParentId,Converter ={StaticResource MandatoryFieldConverter}}"/>

Answer (score 0):

Since you `CheckBox` `IsChecked` is bound to `IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked`, you should have you converter bound directly to the same property of your view model and not to the `CheckBox` (which, obviously, doesn't have a `IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked` property)

```
<CheckBox Name="chkPlaceholder" Command="{Binding PlaceholderCheckboxCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked}" Style="{DynamicResource PlaceholderToggleButtonStyle}" ></CheckBox>

    <TextBox Name="txtUnitFactor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding CommonSecurityAttributes.UnitFactor,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4" >
    <TextBox.Background>

        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomMandatoryFieldConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path= "IsSecurityPlaceholderChecked" />
            <Binding Path= "CommonSecurityAttributes.UnitFactor" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Background> 
</TextBox>
```